# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in firebase error

Tags: java, android, firebase, nosuchmethoderror

My firebase dependencices are of version 10.0.1 . And i tried adding admob dependency of version 10.2.0.

As i know that's why i got that error.

But after getting this error. I removed admob dependency and ran the app again. But still same error. Then I updated all dependencies to version 10.2.0 still same error.

My Error Log:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzdD(Ljava/lang/String;)Z in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzv; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzv' appears in /data/app/com.buckydroid.fireapp-2/base.apk)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                                                                             at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5207)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4802)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4742)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5471)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Does the error go away when you revert back to 10.0.1? What is your compile SDK Version?

Comment: No it doesn't and the compile sdk version is 25

Comment: can you paste your `onCreate()` method code?

Comment: I can but i dont think there is any issue. Because app was working properly before the change in dependencies.. @DharmbirSingh

Comment: Have you increased google play services version?

Comment: Nope............

Comment: And yesterday i got the same error. Then I removed the dependency and it was working properly. @DharmbirSingh

Comment: Are you running the app in emulator? Have you tried to run in on a physical device? I'm not sure if the google services for emulator is already available.

Comment: I'm running app on real device.

Comment: So anyone got the solution for this? I'm still facing this error

Comment: Did you first get those error when you build it on `release`? Because usually this error comes up because your class is obfuscated by proguard

Comment: I was getting error while debugging. I built a signed apk and it's working fine. Thank you @koceeng

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and noticed that I was using a firebase-ui gradle dependency. If you are doing that in your gradle, then it brings its own version of firebase's transitive dependencies.

Removing it solved the problem for me.